# Get metric name in Prometheus Alert

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, alerts

I am setting up a Prometheus alert that will alert on several metrics.
It will look something like this:

```
metric_x > threshold or metric_y > threshold or metric_x > threshold
```

But if this alert goes off, I would like to include something in the description about which metric got alerted on.
Is there a way to know which one of those 3 conditions cause the alarm to go off? Just as a way to add more details in the alarm description?
Is the only way to do that is to have separate alarms or include the metric value in the description?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A metric name under the hood is just another label, which means you can insert it into an annotation. Here's how:

```yaml
- record: foo
  expr: 1
- record: bar
  expr: 2
- alert: test
  expr: foo == 1 or bar == 2
  # You probably need just one of these
  labels:
    name: '{{ .Labels.__name__ }}'
  annotations:
    name: '{{ .Labels.__name__ }}'
```